# If a sequence is non-decreasing and bounded above then it is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The title is the question.

I used the following definition of convergence to prove it: 
 $a_n$ converges to $x \in \mathbb R$  if $\forall \, \epsilon > 0, \, \exists \, N_0 \in \Bbb N$ s.t. $|a_n-x|<\epsilon, \,\forall \, n \geq N_0$

Definition of nondecreasing: $\forall \, n \in \Bbb N,\, a_{n+1} \geq a_n$.

Definition of bounded above: $\exists \, x \in \Bbb R$ s.t. $a_n \leq x \, \forall \, n \in \Bbb N$.

Proof: Set $\epsilon = |a_{n+1} - x|.$ 
$a_n \leq a_{n+1} => a_n - x \leq a_{n+1} - x => |a_n-x| \leq |a_{n+1} - x| => |a_n - x| \leq \epsilon.$ 
For $a_n<a_{n+1}$: The definition of convergence is satisfied. 
$a_n = a_{n+1} \, \forall \, n \in \Bbb N => a_n = a_n \, \forall \, n \in \Bbb N => |a_n - x| = |a_n - a_n| = 0 < \epsilon, \, \forall \epsilon > 0.$

Comment: Your $\varepsilon$ changes with $n$, so it doesn't work.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, $x$ is any upper bound of the sequence. Clearly that can't be right since limits are unique. So what would be the natural choice for $x$?

Comment: The fundamental issue is that you don't define $x$ in your proof (or $n$ in the first line, for that matter).